# how to access elements of structs that in array

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

> ı want to create new node for huffnode structure,

```
(defstruct huffnode

  item
   left 
   right

) 

(setq huffroot (make-huffnode :item huffnode-item (aref arr3 (- (length arr3) 1))
                :left (aref arr3 (-  (length arr3) 1))
                :right (aref arr3 (-  (length arr3) 1))))
```

> i need to get elements from arr3 that stores huffnode nodes, how can i access their data,and copy them to huffroot data

Comment: if you vote - ,please explain

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confused in its grammar so it's not clear what you are asking.

You access elements of an array with `aref` and the slots of a structure with their `accessors` which are (by default) automatically generated from the struct name and slot name e.g. `(huffnode-item x)` gets (or when used as the target of a `setf` sets) the value of the item slot of your huffnode struct stored in `x`

```lisp
; SLIME 2.26
CL-USER> (defstruct huffnode item left right)
HUFFNODE
CL-USER> (defvar *huffroot* (make-huffnode :item "foo" :left nil :right nil))
*HUFFROOT*
CL-USER> (setf (huffnode-item *huffroot*)
           (aref arr3 0)
           (huffnode-left *huffroot*)
           (aref arr3 1)
           (huffnode-right *huffroot*)
           (aref arr3 2)
```